# Can't unpause network printer

Tags: windows-10, network-printer

Just 2 computers in our workgroup (still works under windows 10).
We have a HP 1102w installed on one computer on a USB port. This works fine from that computer, connected using a USB cable.
An annoyance in Windows 7 was that I had to unpause the printer on the other computer after each reboot to allow printing to occur. Now we are on Windows 10, the **Pause Printing** option is checked, and greyed out.
I have tried:

- Uninstall/reinstall
- checked permissions (Everyone can manage)
- Drivers from HP (useless - they won't install a shared printer)
- forced reinstall by using network browse to locate printer

Drive share still works, and i can also access the admin shares (C$, D$, etc)

Any other steps to try?

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Steps:

1. Open Device Manager, uninstall the printer drivers
2. Shut down computer and Unplug the printer
3. Start the computer and then plug in the printer
4. Run Windows Update, because often times those drivers are managed by
   Windows Update
5. During Windows Updates the driver may be found and re-installed.

Comment: printer is not attached to my machine

Answer (score 0):

Your networking seems ok, as you can connect to the shared drives. So I would check permissions again.

To pause or resume printing all documents: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776043%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

> A check mark appears next to Pause Printing when the printer is paused.

Consistent with legacy behaviour.

Any setting or option being greyed out though, would lead me to review the permissions aspect again. Have you considered all permissions, including for example, group and local policies or user access control.

Assigning printer permissions: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773372%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

> By default, the Manage Printers permission is assigned to members of the Administrators and Power Users groups.

Carefully going through the page linked immediately above, may help to trouble shoot the policies and network relationship permissions.

Also see: Group Policy and printing: further down the menu on the Assigning printer permissions link (above).